# How to write XSD which allows inclusion of entire XML document?

Tags: xml, xsd

I have an XSD on the following form:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           targetNamespace="my/sample/namespace" 
           xmlns="my/sample/namespace">
    <xs:element name="Root">
        <xs:complexType>
            <xs:sequence>
                <xs:element name="Child1" type="Child1TYPE" />
                <xs:element name="Child2" type="Child2TYPE" />
            </xs:sequence>
        </xs:complesType>
    <xs:element>

    <xs:simpleType name="Child1TYPE">
        .
        .
        .
</xs:schema>
```

I would like to include an entire XML document using this schema in another XML document. What would the schema of this, second XML document look like? My document should look like:

```
<ContainerDoc xmlns="my/containerdoc/namespace">
    <s:Root xmlns:s="my/sample/namespace">
        <s:Child1>
            .
            .
            .
        </s:Child1>
    </s:Root>
<ContainerDoc>
```

I have tried with something like:

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" 
           targetNamespace="my/containerdoc/namespace" 
           xmlns="my/containerdoc/namespace">
    <xs:element name="ContainerDoc">
        <xs:element name="s:Root" 
                    xmlns:s="my/sample/namespace" />
    </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

but that, apperently, isn't valid XSD (I cannot use the s namespace in the element name of the Root element. Is this possible in an XSD?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Yes, it is possible to write an XSD which allows inclusion of an entire XML document defined by another XSD:

- If the XSDs have the *same namespace*, use `xs:include`.
- If the XSDs have *different namespaces*, use `xs:import`.

The following is a complete, working example of how to use `xs:import` with your XSDs from different namespaces and an XML document instance that is valid per those XSDs:

**This XSD (try.xsd):**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="my/sample/namespace"
           xmlns="my/sample/namespace"
           elementFormDefault="qualified">
  <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="Child1" type="Child1TYPE" />
        <xs:element name="Child2" type="Child2TYPE" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:simpleType name="Child1TYPE">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
  </xs:simpleType>
  <xs:simpleType name="Child2TYPE">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string"/>
  </xs:simpleType>
</xs:schema>
```

**Can be imported by this XSD (try2.xsd):**

```
<xs:schema xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
           targetNamespace="my/containerdoc/namespace"
           xmlns="my/containerdoc/namespace">
  <xs:import namespace="my/sample/namespace" schemaLocation="try.xsd"/>
  <xs:element name="ContainerDoc">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element ref="s:Root" xmlns:s="my/sample/namespace" />
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
</xs:schema>
```

**So that this XML document instance:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ContainerDoc xmlns="my/containerdoc/namespace"
              xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
              xsi:schemaLocation="my/containerdoc/namespace try2.xsd">
  <s:Root xmlns:s="my/sample/namespace">
    <s:Child1/>
    <s:Child2/>
  </s:Root>
</ContainerDoc>
```

**Will be valid.**